# The environment pane in r - global environment setting not in R

Tags: rstudio

The environment pane is not set to R. It simply says global environment yet I need it to show R | Global environment.The second picture is the correct one. My question is how to change the environment pane is 1st picture to the one in the second.

[image: Image 1 - Incorrect setting]

[image: Image 2 - Desired Output]

Comment: Have you opened a R file? if you assign some R variable I think you will see the “R”

Comment: Which version are you using? I tried a number of versions but could replicate you problem